# Grails: store a class literal in the database

Tags: class, grails, grails-orm

I want to store whether something should be a String or an Integer in the database.  My fantasy would be something like this:

```
Class FantasyClass{
  String someInfo
  Class whichClass
}
```

And then I could call it like this:

```
def thisThing = new FantasyClass(someInfo:'lalala',whichClass:String)
```

Is there any workaround to achieve this functionality?

Where I could go like:

```
def getAThing = FantasyClass.get(1)
assert getAThing.whichClass == String
assert 'thisIsAString' instanceof getAThing.whichClass  //THIS IS WHAT I REALLLLLLY WANT!!!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `asType` method

```
def getAThing = FantasyClass.get(1)
assert getAThing.whichClass == String
assert 'thisIsAString'.getClass() == getAThing.someInfo.asType(getAThing.whichClass)
```

Here's a more generic example:

```
def value = 123
def otherThing = new FantasyClass(
   someInfo: value.toString(),
   whichClass: value.getClass()).save()

assert otherThing.someInfo.asType(getAThing.whichClass) instanceof Integer
```

And you can add a helper method to the domain class that will convert the String to the specified type for you:

```
def getTypedValue() {
   someInfo?.asType(foo)
}
```

and then you can do this:

```
assert otherThing.typedValue == 123
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a `Class` field in a domain class without any additional code.  GORM will automatically store it as the fully qualified class name.

For other classes where there's no automatic conversion you need the ability to convert to and from a database type.  To have grails automatically convert your type, you need a hibernate [UserType](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/usertype/UserType.html).  Simply create a class that implements that interface and map the field to it in your domain class:

```
static mapping = {
    whichClass type: MyUserType
}
```

Comment: You don't need any of this - GORM will do all that for you.

Comment: I wasn't aware Classes were handled automatically.  Thanks for the correction.